# Display Streaming DataFrame in Jupyter from Redis Subcription

Tags: python, pandas, redis, jupyter-notebook

I have a Redis pub-sub channel 'price-updates' in redis for which a publisher sets updates for a stock price. I want to display a streaming grid that keeps appending the price updates as they come at the end of the grid.

So far, I have created a non-working version of what I want to do.

```
from streamz import Stream
from streamz.dataframe import DataFrame

source = Stream()
data = []

def handler(message):
    json_data = json.loads(message['data'])
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([json_data]).set_index('sym')

source.map(handler).sink(data.append)
sdf = DataFrame(source)

## Run this in a different thread 
p.subscribe('price-updates')
while True:
    message = p.get_message()
    if message:
        source.emit(message)
        time.sleep(0.001)
## end of thread block


#displayStreamingDataGrid(sdf)
```

I would appreciate if someone with more experience with the sdf could help me do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this without streams. However, I am not getting a the streaming grid that gets updated in-place but rather displaying and clearing the output which is very annoying.

Here is the output widget in one jupyter cell

```
import ipywidgets as iw
from IPython.display import display 

o = iw.Output()
def output_to_widget(df, output_widget): 
    output_widget.clear_output()
    with output_widget: 
        display(df)
o
```

Here is the code to subscribe to redis and get handle the message

```
import redis, json, time

r = redis.StrictRedis(host = HOST, password = PASS, port = PORT, db = DB)
p = r.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
p.subscribe('QUOTES')

mdf = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    message = p.get_message()
    if message:
        json_msg = json.loads(message['data'])
        df = pd.DataFrame([json_msg]).set_index('sym')
        mdf = mdf.append(df)
        output_to_widget(mdf, o)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget to create an html
table which you can update in place without visibly clearing the table between updates.

I put an example notebook here: https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/master/notebooks/misc/In%20place%20html%20table%20update%20demo.ipynb

The trick is to create a widget that displays a table and attaches
an update operation which modifies the table:

```
# Create a proxy widget with a table update method
import jp_proxy_widget

def updateable_table(headers, rows):
    w = jp_proxy_widget.JSProxyWidget()
    w.js_init("""
    # injected javascript for the widget:

    element.update_table = function(headers, rows) {
        element.empty();
        var table = $("<table border style='text-align:center'/>");
        table.appendTo(element);
        var header_row = $("<tr/>");
        for (var i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
            $("<th style='text-align:center'>" + headers[i] + "</th>")
            .width(50)
            .appendTo(header_row);
        }
        header_row.appendTo(table);
        for (var j=0; j<rows.length; j++) {
            var table_row = $("<tr/>").appendTo(table);
            var data_row = rows[j];
            for (var i=0; i<data_row.length; i++) {
                $("<td>" + data_row[i] + "</td>").appendTo(table_row);
            }
        }
    }

    element.update_table(headers, rows);
    """, headers=headers, rows=rows)
    return w

# show the widget
w = updateable_table(headers, rows)
w
```

The code to update the widget

```
# Update the widget 20 times
import time
count = -20
for i in range(21):
    time.sleep(1)
    rows = [rows[-1]] + rows[:-1]  # rotate the rows
    rows[0][0] = count  # change the upper left entry.
    count += 1
    w.element.update_table(headers, rows)
```

updates the table in place with no visible erasure.  The example
notebook linked above also shows how to do the same thing using a
pandas dataframe.